# Horizontal scrolling inside Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, scroll

I have a gallery inside my modal window done via Bootstrap.
I want to be able to horizontally scroll within it using this: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/horz-scroll-with-mouse-wheel/.

The problem is, it scrolls the page behind it, not the actual modal window. When I don't have the Horizontal Scrolling script on, I can scroll in the modal with shift+mousewheel, which is what I want to do width the script(just without using shift ofcourse).

My JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8XdVt/22/

HTML:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://yandex.st/jquery/mousewheel/3.0.6/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <h2>Modal Gallery</h2>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div id="gallery-modal">
                <img src="http://31.media.tumblr.com/67151918dbf1e1ca27ed5a0921970c81/tumblr_n5waphpp4M1st5lhmo1_1280.jpg" alt="">
                <img src="http://31.media.tumblr.com/67151918dbf1e1ca27ed5a0921970c81/tumblr_n5waphpp4M1st5lhmo1_1280.jpg" alt="">
                <img src="http://31.media.tumblr.com/67151918dbf1e1ca27ed5a0921970c81/tumblr_n5waphpp4M1st5lhmo1_1280.jpg" alt="">
            </div>    
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
<h2>Normal Gallery</h2>      
<div id="gallery">
                <img src="http://31.media.tumblr.com/67151918dbf1e1ca27ed5a0921970c81/tumblr_n5waphpp4M1st5lhmo1_1280.jpg" alt="">
                <img src="http://31.media.tumblr.com/67151918dbf1e1ca27ed5a0921970c81/tumblr_n5waphpp4M1st5lhmo1_1280.jpg" alt="">
                <img src="http://31.media.tumblr.com/67151918dbf1e1ca27ed5a0921970c81/tumblr_n5waphpp4M1st5lhmo1_1280.jpg" alt="">
            </div>   
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, made it work! All I did was change the scrolling script, so it doesn't scroll in html and body, but on .modal, which is the main class of the modal window!

Updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8XdVt/28/.

Changed

```
$("html,body").mousewheel(function(event, delta)
```

To

```
$(".modal").mousewheel(function(event, delta)
```