# horizontal scroll in bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

Hi i am trying add a horizontal scroll bar in bootstrap modal. I know horizontal scroll bars are not a good idea but in my case i have dynamic content which can have variable width so i want to make modal body scroll-able horizontally when width exceed modal body's width.

here is what i have tried

```
<div class="modal-header">
<h3 class="modal-title">Decomposition</h3>

  <div class="modal-body">
  <div class="scoll-tree">
       <div class="list-group" ng-repeat="item in items"> 
          <a class="list-group-item" href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="getChildren(item)">{{item.value}}</a>
       </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.modal-body {
     max-width: 900px;
     overflow-x: auto;
}
```

here is the fiddle what i have tried..
https://jsfiddle.net/4duq2svh/2/

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You describe what you have tried, but not the results - if any. How does it look? What is the actual problem? Does your example work partially? Not at all?

Comment: Does this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23848029/horizontal-scrolling-inside-bootstrap-modal) help with your horizontal scroll.

Comment: @SilverSkin my solution is not working it doesn't show any scroll bar

Comment: @bbh no that issue is talking about something else

Comment: @arsinawaz, can you please add a jsfiddle with your code.

Comment: please check the fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question, I solved it by calculating the width of scroll-tree div based on number of list-groups inside, as one single list group is 180px wide the width will be 180 * numberOfItems. here is the code:

```
$scope.getStyle = function(){
    var numberOfItems = $scope.tree.length;

    return {
        width  : 200 * numberOfItems + 'px',
        overflowX: 'auto'
    }   
}

<div class="modal-body" style="overflow-x: auto;">>
   <div class="scoll-tree" ng-style="getStyle();">
      <div class="list-group" ng-repeat="item in items"> 
        <a class="list-group-item" href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="getChildren(item)">{{item.value}}</a>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

check https://jsfiddle.net/4duq2svh/3/

**HTML**

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="scoll-tree">
        <div class="list-group" ng-repeat="item in items"> 
            <a class="list-group-item" href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="getChildren(item)">{{item.value}}</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.modal-body {
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
.scoll-tree {
    width:5000px;
}
```

**JS**

```
var totalwidth = 190 * $('.list-group').length;

$('.scoll-tree').css('width', totalwidth);
```

Here I am calculating `.scoll-tree` width using jQuery to help horizontal scroll bar appear.

Comment: it did make scroll bar to appear but the modal body and scroll bar not growing with the content.

Comment: @arsinawaz: can you make a fiddle showing your prb?

Comment: here you go as you can see it show list-groups in next line instead of showing in one line with a scroll bar https://jsfiddle.net/4duq2svh/2/